# Andrew Ng's Coursera Assignment - Training full Trigger Word detection model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

In Andrew Ng's Deep Learning Coursera classes, there's an assignment on trigger word detection (example, not mine: [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/bhagwatvyas/trigger-word-detection-deeplearning-coursera/blob/master/Trigger_word_detection-v1.ipynb)).

In the assignment, they simply provided the trained model because they claim it took several hours to train using the 4000+ training examples with GPUs.

Instead of just using the provided model, I tried creating my own training examples using their functions, and then training the model from scratch.  The raw audio files remain unchanged.  There were 2 background files, so I made sure that there were 2000 training examples for each background:

```
n_train_per_bg = 2000
n_train = len(backgrounds)*n_train_per_bg
orig_X_train = np.empty((n_train, Tx, n_freq))
orig_Y_train = np.empty((n_train, Ty , 1))

for bg in range(len(backgrounds)):
    for n in range(n_train_per_bg):
        print("bg: {}, n: {}".format(bg, n))
        x, y = create_training_example(backgrounds[bg], activates, negatives)
        orig_X_train[bg*n_train_per_bg + n, :, :] = x.T
        orig_Y_train[bg*n_train_per_bg + n, :, :] = y.T

np.save('./XY_train/orig_X_train.npy', orig_X_train)
np.save('./XY_train/orig_Y_train.npy', orig_Y_train)
```

However, after running for an hour, the results I got were quite disappointing.  One of the later examples in the same exercise shows their properly functioning model displaying a probability spike when the trigger word "activate" is being detected around the 400 mark on the x-axis:

[image: Correct answer]

and here's mine, which not only isn't detecting anything, but is simply flatlining!:

[image: After 1 hour training]

The only modifications I made were:

- changing the learning rate for the Adam optimizer from 0.0001 to 0.0010
- setting the `batch_size` to 600

I understand that I probably still need to incorporate many more epochs, but am quite surprised that the output probability would be flat with no change.  Am I doing something horribly wrong or do I just have to trust that the model will converge to something that makes more sense?

Comment: Couple of points to make: the thing about Adam optimizer is that you generally don't need to play with the learning rate. What was the original batch size? 600 seems a bit high and you don't have to take my word for it https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=en  Finally I'd suggest you to take very small subset of the dataset and try to overfit to that subset to check if everything works as expected. Then slightly increase your dataset and train again.

Comment: @HarryStuart Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @thushv89 no I haven’t unfortunately

Comment: So just to clarify you get completely bad results if you make those two changes and get better performance without those two changes?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. At lesat in my experience.